# android studio emulator black screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, hyper-v, amd-processor

Could you help me to start emulator. It never started before on this PC. When I started it I just see black screen and than error. Also I have the same problem with genymotion.

[image]

I tried different options: x86_64, x86, various API, cold boot, wipe date, press power button. Reboot PC)) If need something more, please tell me!
I investigated this issue but nothing helps. My setup:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]